# Context file getting over written in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

```
   <import resource="classpath:context2.xml"/>

   <import resource="classpath:context3.xml" />
```

Here Context1.xml is getting over written by context2.xml, context 1.xml and context2.xml are both MDB's. context3.xml is not having issues.
COntext 1 and context2 have some same Bean ID's but have different properties and references.

Comment: <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.fedex.pdmgr.util.ApplicationContextProvider">
       </bean>
       <import resource="classpath:context1.xml"/>
       
       <import resource="classpath:context2.xml"/>
       
       <import resource="classpath:context3.xml" />
       
</beans>

Comment: Your issue is incomplete.
Provide some code for clear picture id the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution . I was using same Bean ID and thought that it was a pre defined bean ID. I did not have much knowledge on spring . So i studied a bit and found out that u can give any bean ID u want for the class which you are referring to.